Excel: Trying to sum by various criteria but ignoring repeating values
I've a large dataset where I want to sum values by various criteria. The only issue is that some of these values repeat so that a SUMIFS function double, triple etc. counts the values. Is there a formula where I can "tell" my SUMIFS function to only count each value once?
I've included a made-up basic example of the data and what I'm trying to do, hopefully this makes sense. I want to sum for each value that is less or more than 400 for HU only. I've shown the manual, correct results, and then what happens when I use SUMIFS.

Thanks!

TM use table markdown formatting to show your example data, so it's easy to copy. Have you tried using the UNIQUE function? it gets rid of duplicates.

Is it resolved now or is it still pending ? I don't see any response here?

Okay nearly there, but the last step is bugged, if you have acces to Office 365, use this LET function:
=LET(_Data,J1:L16,  
_UniData,UNIQUE(_Data),
_Row1,CHOOSECOLS(_UniData,1),
_Row2,CHOOSECOLS(_UniData,2),
_Row3,CHOOSECOLS(_UniData,3),
_Argument1,"HU",
_Argument2,"<"&400,
_Calc,SUMIFS(_Row3,_Row2,_Argument1,_Rows3,Argument2)

I'm running out of time, but the SUMIFS is still giving  #VALUE error, and I'm not sure why, but hope someone can fix that (or I'll look into it tomorrow).

Here is one way of getting the desired output:
• If all the categories are needed with the labels, and if the Column J is not included as a criterion then, the following will return a tabular data with the total of all HU as shown in screenshot:


• Formula used in cell N1
=LET(
     _Data, J1:L16,
     _ReqD, DROP(_Data,,1),
     _Vals, TAKE(_ReqD,,-1),
     _HU, TAKE(_ReqD,,1),
     _Less, SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(_Vals,(_HU="HU")*(_Vals<400)))),
     _Greater, SUM(UNIQUE(FILTER(_Vals,(_HU="HU")*(_Vals>400)))),
     HSTACK("Total HU "&{"<400";">400";""}, VSTACK(_Less,_Greater,_Less+_Greater)))


• If the Column J is included as a criterion then, use the following:
=LET(
     _Data, J1:L16,
     _Vals, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _HU, INDEX(_Data,,2),
     _Less, SUM(DROP(UNIQUE(FILTER(_Data,(_HU="HU")*(_Vals<400))),,2)),
     _Greater, SUM(DROP(UNIQUE(FILTER(_Data,(_HU="HU")*(_Vals>400))),,2)),
     HSTACK("Total HU "&{"<400";">400";""},
     VSTACK(_Less,_Greater,_Less+_Greater)))


A shorter method will be like as follows:
• When <400
=SUM(DROP(UNIQUE(FILTER(J1:L16,(K1:K16="HU")*(L1:L16<400))),,2))


• When >400
=SUM(DROP(UNIQUE(FILTER(J1:L16,(K1:K16="HU")*(L1:L16>400))),,2))


One another, I was only trying to make it shorter, anyways here is a way using with ETA LAMBDA


=LET(
     _Data, J1:L16,
     _Vals, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _HU, INDEX(_Data,,2),
     _Less, FILTER(_Data,(_HU="HU")*(_Vals<400)),
     _Greater, FILTER(_Data,(_HU="HU")*(_Vals>400)),
     _Sum, TOCOL(BYCOL(IFNA(CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(HSTACK(_Less,_Greater)),3,6),0),SUM)),
     HSTACK("Total HU "&{"<400";">400";""},VSTACK(_Sum,SUM(_Sum))))


